# phpcs with VScode - how do I disable the line length warning?

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpcs

I am working on some legacy code, and VScode is highlighting a lot of lines because of some warnings like `Line exceeds 85 characters, contains 91 characters`. It's pretty annoying, and I'd like to raise that limit to at least 120 chars, or even disable it completely.
My vertical ruler is already set to 120.

How can I move or remove that limit? I've been looking everywhere but I can't find a a working answer... this is my project's `settings.json`

```
{
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 120
}
```

Comment: I've partially solved it by setting the Warning Severity setting to 6... at least I don't have those warnings anymore.

Comment: how did you set the warning severity to 6?

Comment: In settings.json you add `"phpcs.warningSeverity": 6`

Answer (score 5):

Edit phpcs settings in VS Code and make sure "PHP Sniffer: Standard" is blank (so that it looks for your custom ruleset file).

Create file "phpcs.xml" in your project root, containing a ruleset like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="MyRuleset">
  <!-- Scan all files in directory -->
  <file>.</file>

  <!-- Ignore Composer dependencies -->
  <exclude-pattern>vendor/</exclude-pattern>

  <!-- Show colors in console -->
  <arg value="-colors"/>

  <!-- Show sniff codes in all reports -->
  <arg value="ns"/>

  <!-- Use PSR-12 as a base -->
  <rule ref="PSR12"/>

  <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength.TooLong">
      <severity>0</severity>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the error `phpcs: The "c:\Users\paul\OneDrive\Games\Scratch\Shops\PP\Site\phpcs.xml" coding standard is not installed. Please review your configuration an try again.`